# How to toggle a custom mapType in Google API?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, toggle

We have a custom mapType in Google maps API v.3 and it's working fine with our own tiles.

However, our custom tile overlay applies only to a limited area at specific zooms, but users are free to move outside that area and to other zoom levels. When they do, we would like to hide or remove the custom mapType option that we have on the map initial default view. (This in order to avoid the map trying to pull in tiles that don't exist on our server.)

We have tried a few operations on the array specifying the mapTypes, but to no effect.

These do not work (we start with "custom" in array index 0):

map.mapTypeControlOptions.mapTypeIds = ["roadmap", "satellite", "hybrid", "terrain"];

map.mapTypeControlOptions.mapTypeIds.shift();

Further, when the user clicks a button near our map, we want to set the map center and zoom, then re-show or re-add our custom mapType button to the map type control options, thus the need to toggle it.

Our map is here: http://www.cornell.edu/maps2/

-Ken

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like you don't need a custom map type but rather an overlay. Something like this:
https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-hideshow